# WFS Multiple features in Openlayers

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers-2

I want to get multiple WFS features and edit

My Code

```
this.wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS-T" , {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), this.saveStrategy],
        projection:  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
        protocol:    new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version:     "1.1.0",
            srsName:     "EPSG:3857",
            url:         "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureNS:   "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mall",
            extractAttributes: true,
            featureType: ['stores' , 'store_point'],
            geometryName: 'geom'
        })

    });
```

But i can not edit features

Error Message :

```
<ows:ExceptionText>Feature type 'stores,store_point' is not available: </ows:ExceptionText>
```

Comment: what is your datastore called?

Comment: It is  Postgresql

Comment: but what is it's name in geoserver?

Comment: sorry i don't get it. What do you men excatly ?

Comment: You are requesting features from a datastore - is it called 'stores' or 'point' or something else entirely

Comment: I want to calling stores and store_point ( featureType: ['stores' , 'store_point'], sorry I wrote it wrong ) and edit in one wfs layer

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable jsonp in your Geoserver to be able to post code

In order to edit you need the following code:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'yourfeatureNS',
    featureType: 'stores',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var s = new XMLSerializer();

var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'stores',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                opaque: false,
                attributions: []
            })
        }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1, 51.50]),
        zoom: 13
    })
});

var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

map.addInteraction(interaction);

interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: s.serializeToString(formatWFS.writeTransaction([e.feature], null, null, formatGML))
    }).done();
});
```